# Why does selectBooleanCheckbox send me to the bottom of the page on click?

Tags: primefaces, backend, xhtml

I am using Primefaces, and in my xhtml file, I have two "selectBooleanCheckbox" locations, and whenever I click them they send me to the bottom of the page. I checked the tags and all I have is an id and a value.

Could there be something on the Java backend that could cause it and if so is there something I could look out for?

Here is the xhtml side of it:

```
<p:outputLabel for="HasRoleAdmin" value="Admin: " />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="HasRoleAdmin" value="#{UserMgt.newadminrole}"/>
<h:message for="HasRoleAdmin" style="color:red"/>

<p:outputLabel for="HasRoleUser" value="User: " />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="HasRoleUser" value="#{UserMgt.newuserrole}"/>
<h:message for="HasRoleUser" style="color:red"/>
```

On the java side....

```
public boolean isNewadminrole() {
    return newadminrole;
}

public void setNewadminrole(boolean Newhasroleadmin) {
    newadminrole = Newhasroleadmin;
}

public boolean isNewuserrole() {
    return newuserrole;
}

public void setNewuserrole(boolean Newuserrole) {
    newuserrole = Newuserrole;
}
```

Comment: share your code! we are not magicians that we see what you think

Comment: @Volzy forry about that, changes are made and code is there now

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] using https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test